# Unresolved __builtin_ia32_stmxcsr

Tags: eclipse, gcc, intel, sse, nvidia

I have inherited code, trying to compile with gcc on Linux.

what library am I looking for that has __builtin_ia32_stmxcsr ?

apologies --  i was too fast to submit;  running gcc inside of Nvidia Eclipse.  actual error message is "Functuion .  . . could not be resolved"  so i jumped the conclusion i needed to reference some lib.  As the offending lines hav a :#if defined(**SSE**)  I take it to mean that the -msse2 switch is present although i cannot seem to find a copyh of the compile command line. [just learning this Eclipse tool -- very new!]

Comment: apologies --  i was too fast to submit;  running gcc inside of Nvidia Eclipse.  actual error message is "Functuion .  . . could not be resolved"  so i jumped the conclusion i needed to reference some lib.  As the offending lines:#if defined(__SSE__)
      orig_mxcsr = __builtin_ia32_stmxcsr ();
     our_mxcsr = orig_mxcsr | MXCSR_DAZ | MXCSR_FTZ;
 __builtin_ia32_ldmxcsr (our_mxcsr);
#endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in eclipses indexer with gcc's `__builtin*` functions. The bug report is at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352537

The problem is that even the glibc/gcc libraries themselves use these `__builtin*` functions, so eclipse complains about a faulty `xmmintrin.h` etc., which is of course nonsense.

There is a workaround given in the bug report, you can add the function prototypes as user defined macros for the indexer, but of course this becomes tedious if there are a few more and some type checking abilities are lost.

Comment: turns out I had a power outage; when i rebooted and restarted eclipse the problem disappeared!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to link with anything - the "builtin" in the name is a clue that it's a gcc built-in (intrinsic) compiler function.

However you do need to be compiling for an x86 target with SSE enabled for this to be recognised, e.g. `gcc -msse2 ...`.

Note that you can use the `_mm_getcsr` intrinsic from `<xmmintrin.h>` instead of `__builtin_ia32_stmxcsr` - this would be a little more portable.

Comment: Right.  And bravo for pointing out that `__builtin_` should be avoided when equivalent portable intrinsics are available.

Comment: thanks.  i tried your suggestion of _mm_getcsr;  still get error message of this function ... could not be resolved.  any thoughts ?

Comment: Did you `#include <xmmintrin.h>` ? Note also that you can temporarily #ifdef out this block of code if it's holding you up - it just turns off denormal handling for performance reasons - you can omit this for now and get the rest of the code compiling and come back to it later - it won't affect functionality, just performance.

Comment: Good suggestions, but actually this is a bug in eclipse.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz: thanks for the clarification - I don't use Eclipse and wasn't aware that it had this problem.

Comment: apparently some builtin functions are deprecated in gcc 4 [  http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2005-12/msg00149.html  ]